# Multithreaded Socket programming server is getting messages from only 1 client thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, pthreads, client-server

For a benchmarking task, I'm creating multiple server workers with the same socket descriptor and client workers with separate connections.

Though client threads are sending a copy of the same message for each thread. The server shows it's received only one copy of each message, not all copies, sent by sending by all client threads.

for 4 threads and 2 messages {0,1} , client output

```
client 3Wrote 0
 client 1Wrote 1
 client 0Wrote 0
 client 1Wrote 0
 client 2Wrote 0
 client 3Wrote 1
 client 2Wrote 1
```

Where as server output

```
Server 0 Received - 0
Server 2 Received - 1
```

Why aren't rest of the messages showing up ? Or they were never actually sent by the client ?

```
void *clientWorker(void *threadarg) {
    struct workDetails *thisWork;
    thisWork = (struct workDetails *) threadarg;
    int threadcount = thisWork->threadcount;
    int chunkSize = thisWork->chunkSize;
    char *serverIp = thisWork->serverIp;
    char *dataStore = thisWork->dataStore;

    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    char *buffer = (char *) calloc(chunkSize, sizeof(char));
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening client socket");
    server = gethostbyname(serverIp);
    if (server == NULL) error("Could not detect server by node name");

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *) server->h_addr,
          (char *) &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
          server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORTNO);
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("Server is not up.");
    long totalPackets = oneGBtoByte / (chunkSize * threadcount);
    long i;
    for (i = 0; i < totalPackets; ++i) {
        sprintf(buffer, "%ld", i);
        if (write(sockfd, buffer, chunkSize) < 0)
            error("ERROR writing to socket");
        else {
            lock_guard<mutex> guard(cout_mutex);
            cout << " client " << thisWork->threadid << "Wrote " << i << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << " client " << thisWork->threadid << "Exit";
    pthread_exit((void *) NULL);
}

void *serverWorker(void *threadarg) {
    struct workDetails *thisWork;
    thisWork = (struct workDetails *) threadarg;
    int threadcount = thisWork->threadcount;
    int chunkSize = thisWork->chunkSize;
    char *dataStore = thisWork->dataStore;
    int sockfd = thisWork->sockfd;
    char *buffer = new char[chunkSize];

    while (1) {

        if(read(sockfd, buffer, chunkSize) > 0){
            lock_guard<mutex> guard(cout_mutex);
            cout << "Server " << thisWork->threadid << " Received - " << buffer << endl;
        }
    }
    pthread_exit((void *) NULL);
}
```

Comment: Sharing the same socket descriptor across threads is generally a bad idea, and if it's a TCP socket it's always a bad idea (because you can't control which bytes from the TCP stream will go to which thread, and in the inevitable case where thread A ends up with half of the incoming TCP message and thread B ends up with the other half, neither thread can correctly handle the message)

Comment: I guess entire message chunk goes to a particular thread only. `read(sockfd, buffer, chunkSize)` is threadsafe.

Comment: Your guess is overly optimistic at best. The point is that `read(sockfd, buffer, chunkSize)` is *not* guaranteed to obtain `chunkSize` bytes. In particular, if you have multiple threads sharing a socket, it may receive only 1 byte of one peer's message. Or it may receive bytes of several peers' messages interspersed. Code can be both thread-safe and incoherent.

Comment: To elaborate on what Gil mentioned above -- TCP is a stream-based protocol, not a message-based one; that means that a TCP stream only guarantees the delivery and ordering of the bytes it transports, it doesn't provide any message-framing capabilities.  So the data passed to the TCP layer via a single call to send() may be received at the other end by multiple calls to recv(), or contrariwise the data passed in via multiple calls to send() might be received all together via a single recv() call.  Your receiving code will need to account for that -- hard to do if multiple threads are involved.

Comment: So you are saying server shouldn't ever (I mean generally .... ) use threads ?

Comment: I wouldn't go that far -- you can write a server with or without threads; however if you do use threads, I would recommend making sure that each file descriptor is owned exclusively by a single thread (i.e. so that thread is the only thread that has access to that file descriptor, and that thread is responsible for closing the file descriptor when it is done using it)

Comment: @sapy: No, that is not what they are saying.  You CAN have 1 thread reading from a socket while another thread writes to the same socket. But you CANNOT have multiple threads reading from the same socket at the same time, or multiple threads writing to the same socket at the same time, unless you serialize access to the socket to avoid concurrency issues and data corruption. Otherwise, use a separate thread for each socket, don't share the socket across multiple threads.

Comment: You have a problem with a server and you post client code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `accept connection code` was in the main thread(As not visible in the code). And hence server accepted only one connection though client tried to create 4 connection. And the out put did not reveal this issue as the code doesn't send an acknowledgment back or forth. (No ping pong . ideally most receive is followed by send ack, and every send is followed by recv ack).

When I moved that accept connection code to thread worker . It worked as intended.

```
void *serverWorker(void *threadarg) {
    struct workDetails *thisWork;
    thisWork = (struct workDetails *) threadarg;
    int threadcount = thisWork->threadcount;
    int chunkSize = thisWork->chunkSize;
    char *dataStore = thisWork->dataStore;
    int sockfd = thisWork->sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in cli_addr; // = thisWork->cli_addr;
    char *buffer = new char[chunkSize];


    listen(sockfd, 5);
    socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    sockfd = ::accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR on accept");

    while (1) {
        if (recv(sockfd, buffer, chunkSize, 0) > 0) {
            //lock_guard<mutex> guard(cout_mutex);
            //cout << "Server " << thisWork->threadid << " Received - " << buffer << endl;
            buffer[chunkSize] = NULL;
            strncat(dataStore, buffer, strlen(buffer));
            if (strlen(dataStore) == oneGBtoByte) {
                cout << "Done - " << endl;
                storeInfile(created, dataStore);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //End
    delete[] buffer;
    pthread_exit((void *) NULL);

}
```

How ever what ever @jeremy-friesner or @gil-hamilton told is true. But those issues are not important here , as I'm only interested in total byte received and not who received which chunk.